# Port Haskell code using Control.Parallel to Scala

Tags: scala, haskell, concurrency, multicore, scalaz

The Haskell code below uses `par` and `pseq` to do some multicore number-crunching as a toy to show several cores being used. What would be the easiest and most idiomatic way to express this in Scala? Futures and Promises seem promising (ahem) and I have been looking at `scalaz.concurrent`, e.g. [this example](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/example/src/main/scala/scalaz/example/concurrent/Fibs.scala), but I can't find docs to explain it all.

```
import Control.Parallel

main = a `par` b `par` c `pseq` print (a + b + c)
  where
      a = ack 3 10
      b = fac 42
      c = fib 35

fac 0 = 1
fac n = n * fac (n-1)

ack 0 n = n+1
ack m 0 = ack (m-1) 1
ack m n = ack (m-1) (ack m (n-1))

fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

Comment: Shouldn't a, b, and c be force-d in order to actually do parallel work?

Comment: That's not necessary, at least when compiling with `ghc -O2 -threaded Par.hs --make -fforce-recomp`

Comment: @jozefg: They must be evaluated at least as soon as their sum is printed.

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes, I wasn't sure if GHC would eval them to WHNF and then do the full evaluation during the print, on a single core.

Comment: Oh right... Im stupid.. Thank you for the clarification

Comment: Note the semantics of sparks - if resources aren't available GHC won't waste a thread on the spare lazy future. So this makes par very cheap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can translate your example in Scala like so:

```
import concurrent.{Await, Future, future}
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import concurrent.duration.Duration

object Main extends App {

  val fac: Int => Int = {
    case 0 => 1
    case n => n * fac(n-1)
  }

  val ack: (Int, Int) => Int = {
    case (0, n) => n + 1
    case (m, 0) => ack (m-1, 1)
    case (m, n) => ack (m-1, ack(m, n-1))
  }

  val fib: Int => Int = {
    case 0 => 0
    case 1 => 1
    case n => fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
  }

  val fa = future { ack(3, 10) }
  val fb = future { fac(42) }
  val fc = future { fib(35) }

  val x = for (((a, b), c) <- fa zip fb zip fc) yield (a + b + c)

  val result = Await.result(x, Duration.Inf) //awaiting synchronously after the result
  println(s"Value is: $result")

}
```

The `future { fib(3, 10) }` bit will create an asynchronous computation which will run on a different execution thread and will return a `Future` object. You can then compose all your futures into one big future which will provide the list of all the results, using `Future.sequence`.

We can map the result of this latter future into the sum of the results, thus obtaining the final value.

With this final future we can do several things. We can compose it further or we can attach callbacks on it or we can wait synchronously for a specified duration of time. In my example I am waiting in a synchronous fashion after the result for an infinite period of time.

Comment: Thanks! After rewriting `ack`, `fib` and `fac` to be tail recursive and use BigInts, this works for me.

Comment: @jaybee I'm glad. I had a feeling you might need BigInt here, but I didn't focus on the numeric computation stuff.

Comment: BTW why did you use `val` to introduce `fac` et al, rather than `def`? I'm curious as to the implications of picking one over the other.

Comment: `def` would have created a `fac` method in the object `Main`. By using `val` `fac` is now a function, that is an instance of the `Function1` trait (actually, because I'm using the `case` syntax it's an instance of `PartialFunction`). You can go either way, but I used the `val` approach with pattern matching to be closer to the functional feel.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use futures, because they are part of the standard library since 2.10 and very easy to use. I will not port your code, but give you an example, so that you get an idea.

```
// not tailrec, will stack overflow for larger numbers
def fib(x: Int): Int = x match {
  case 0 | 1 => x
  case x => fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)
}

import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

// create all the futures
val futures = Seq(future(fib(3)), future(fib(4)), future(fib(5)))

// make a Future[Seq[Int]] out of Seq[Future[Int]] and sum the ints
val sumFuture = Future.sequence(futures).map(_.sum)

// if the future is completed successfully print the result
sumFuture.onSuccess {
  case x => println(x)
}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much. I've got something working along these lines but using `Await.result` to wait for the functions to complete.